# Sorting by multiple rules

Tags: python, sorting

Dictionary, which keys are three separated characters, and keys are different sized lists, use sort/sorted function to sort this dictionary by the length of values array. If the length of values array equal, sort it by the 3rd element(character) in key. If collision appears in this case as well, sort it by 2nd element in key in ascending order. Character size(upper/lower) does not matters.

I’ve managed to sort it by length of values but I can’t quite find solution how to find collision and using other two sorting rules.

```py
x = {("a", "B", "b"):[2, 0], ("A", "c", "b"):[2,1], ("d", "a", "C"):[0, 0, 0], 
     ("A", "A", "A"):[2], ("e", "e", "t"):[2, 3]}

sort1 = sorted(x.items(), key = lambda x: x[1].__len__())

input = {("a", "B", "b"):[2, 0], ("A", "c", "b"):[2,1], ("d", "a", "C"):[0, 0, 0], 
         ("A", "A", "A"):[2], ("e", "e", "t"):[2, 3]}

expected_output = [(("A", "A", "A"):[2]),(("e", "e", "t"):[2, 3]),
                   (("A", "B", "b"):[2, 1]),(("a", "c", "b"):[2, 0]),
                   (("d", "a", "C"),[0, 0, 0])]
```

Comment: key like `key = lambda x: (len(x[1],x[1])` you get the idea: one tuple item per criterion

Comment: Can you explain your expected output? I think that's contradicting with your explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use a `tuple` for the `key` argument.
Here I use `ord` function to sort chars in descending mode.

```
x = {("a", "B", "b"):[2, 0], ("A", "c", "b"):[2,1], ("d", "a", "C"):[0, 0, 0], ("A", "A", "A"):[2], ("e", "e", "t"):[2, 3]}

sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: (len(x[1]), -ord(x[0][2].lower()), x[0][1].lower()))

[(('A', 'A', 'A'), [2]),
 (('e', 'e', 't'), [2, 3]),
 (('a', 'B', 'b'), [2, 0]),
 (('A', 'c', 'b'), [2, 1]),
 (('d', 'a', 'C'), [0, 0, 0])]
```

Comment: There is no where I can see OP talking about descending order. That output does not match with expected output also.

Comment: @Austin I think OP simply was not super precise in posting output. I deduced "descending order" by the output (hopefully OP was precise on this aspect), and by request for ascending order on second element, don't you agree?

Comment: Feels the same when you say, but still OP is expecting a different output.

Comment: @Austin expected output is not even syntactically valid

Comment: Forget syntax, the order on the other hand is important (because sorting) which it looks different from your output.

Comment: @Austin if you compare input and output, some of key-value pairs are mixed up, and some of the output keys does not even exist in input. But the order looks coherent to what OP describe (If not please tell me where). Unless OP wants something completely different from a simple sorting, this is the only thing I can think OP wants. But most likely I'm missing something, where this output contradicts OP's expected (apart from being different)?

Comment: I believe your output is what OP wants or let he/she take the call (very unlikely I would expect a comment). I'm done and sorry I didn't notice the discrepancy between key-value in the OP's output. :)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yeah sorting by the 3rd element was descending order... my bad. I didn’t notice that. However your answer provided me how to think about the solution about these sorting problems. Thanks guys! This task was on my semestral test and I had no clue how to do that.. couldn’t find any proper way. The only difference is when applying 3rd sorting rule “compare 2nd character in keys” its actually B vs c. Your solution did B before c(in problem description is said, that we should ignore upper or lower case, so dunno why the expected output vas c before B)

Comment: Got desired output by changing "key=lambda x: (len(x[1]), -ord(x[0][2].lower()), x[0][1].lower()))” to key=lambda x: (len(x[1]), -ord(x[0][2].lower()), -ord(x[0][1].lower())))